# reload the page after clicking 'OK" using Sweetalert

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert2

Trying to reload the page after a success message, but it is not reloading..

I have this code

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: '/action.cfm?method=quote',
  data: datastring,
  success: function(data) {
    var valid = $.trim(data);
    if (valid.toLowerCase().indexOf("error") == '-1') {
      localStorage.setItem("swal", swal({
        title: "Good job!",
        text: 'Thanks',
        type: "success",
        showConfirmButton: true
      }).then(function() {
        location.reload();
      }));
      localStorage.getItem("swal");
    } else {
      swal("Oops", data, "error");
    }
  }
});
```

but I get an error on this

```
(index):389 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at Object.success ((index):389)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
    at done (jquery-1.12.4.js:9840)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery-1.12.4.js:10311)
```

Comment: `localStorage.setItem` does not return a `promise`, hence no `then()`.

Comment: `swal()` is returning the Promise, not `localStorage.setItem`.

Comment: I think its sweet alert 2 that has promises

Comment: i am using sweetalert 2

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Swal.fire()` instead of `swal()`?

Comment: ok, let me try that

Comment: I fixed your tags

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using a new version of Sweetalert (below, in jsfiddle, you can find 2.1.2) - I got warning about using deprecated `showConfirmButton` and `type` properties. Here's a slightly amended code that works in jsfiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: {},
        success: function(data) {
            var valid = $.trim(data);
            if (valid.toLowerCase().indexOf("error") == '-1') {
                localStorage.setItem("swal", swal({
                    title: "Good job!",
                    text: 'Thanks',
                    icon: "success",
                    button: true
                }).then(function() {
                    console.log('sth');
                    location.reload();
                }));
                localStorage.getItem("swal");
            } else {
                swal("Oops", data, "error");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wlecki/rwc58h17/

But overall, If you have to store it in the browser's localstorage, I suggest you store just a sweetalert options there, and use them if you want to display a sweetalert:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: '/echo/json/',
            data: {},
            success: function(data) {
                var valid = $.trim(data);
                if (valid.toLowerCase().indexOf("error") == '-1') {
                    localStorage.setItem("swal", JSON.stringify({
                        title: "Good job!",
                        text: 'Thanks',
                        icon: "success",
                        button: true
                    }));

                    swal(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("swal"))).then(() => location.reload());
            } else {
                swal("Oops", data, "error");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wlecki/71vzasxh/